# Why is the code to open Tony's workroom a three-digit number and does it have any meaning in or out of universe?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man, iron-man-2008

In *Iron Man* (2008), Stark calls Pepper down to his workroom to help him with his ARC reactor. When she comes down, she types in the code "106" into a keypad, seen at 49:13. Why is the code only three digits? That makes for a very insecure code - did Tony not care about security protocols? Or is it a callback to the comics, or to an in-universe event, or is it an easter egg?

Comment: I'm guessing it's because that's how Gwyneth tapped her fingers onto the glass when they filmed the scene and they built the effect afterwards.

Comment: Possible, yes...

Comment: The glass is very easy to break as we see in the films. I'd imagine it's not really a viable security device, after all if the intruder is already there Tony has worse problems.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> did Tony not care about security protocols"

For all we know, each button press is actually taking samples from her skin, and running various analyses for identity, physiological arousal, intoxicants, poisons, pathogens, and other potential threats. Tony also has Jarvis potentially carrying out various security monitoring tasks in the lab, and probably throughout the house. Anyone who gets to the lab door may well have already been vetted several different ways.

As such, the code is probably just there to prevent guests from accidentally walking into an area that could be dangerous to them. Shorter is better to avoid unnecessary delays to Pepper when she needs to get in, which comes in pretty handy when her boss is dying on the floor. (And at least it isn't just 1-2-3.)

Comment: "...physiological arousal, intoxicants..." would those be to keep Tony himself out when he's "in a state"?

Comment: @FreeMan: one can only hope.